# cannot set combo selected index when user type

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedindex

I have a form with databound combobox, with dropstyle set as dropdown, so users could type in the combobox.

My problem is that when users type in the combobox and the value typed matches one of the values bound to the combobox it won't change the selectedindex, even though I've tried too. Instead, it sets the selected index to -1 (and thus the selected value is null).

Can anyone help? here's my code (one of my tries, i tried other approaches but none helped).

```
private void setCombo()
{
        comboFromOther.DisplayMember = "tbl10_KupaID";
        comboFromOther.ValueMember = "tbl10_KupaID";
        comboFromOther.DataSource = dsKupotGemel.Tables[0];
}

private void comboToOther_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        comboDetail = changedComboText(2, comboToOther.Text);
        textToOther.Text = comboDetail[0];
        if (comboDetail[0] == "")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            comboToOther.SelectedIndex = System.Int32.Parse(comboDetail[1]);
            comboToOther.SelectedValue = System.Int32.Parse(comboDetail[2]);
        } 
    }

    private string[] changedComboText(int iComboType, string comboString)
    {
        if (groupCalculate.Visible == true)
        {
            groupCalculate.Visible = false;
        }
        string[] kupaDetail = new string[3];
        kupaDetail[0] = "";
        kupaDetail[1] = "";
        kupaDetail[2] = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= dsKupotGemel.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
           if (comboString == dsKupotGemel.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString())
           {
                 kupaDetail[0] = dsKupotGemel.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
                 kupaDetail[1] = i.ToString();
                 kupaDetail[2] = comboString;
                 break;
           }
           else
           {

           }
        }
   return kupaDetail;
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, you should only set one of `SelectedIndex` *or* `SelectedValue`, not both (setting one should set the other).

Comment: Ic. is correct. Just set SelectedValue to correct value from your data source, and comboBox will fire selection change event (ex. SelectedIndexChanged) and value/index on combo box will be correct. I have a working code example if your interested.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: it doesn't help. I've tried to setting just the value or just the index and no help. when I just set the value I get null, and when I just set the index I get -1.

Comment: I don't know why, but the ..._textchanged fires up twice for each type (i.e if I type 8, it will fire twice the textchanged event). 
If I create an event outside of the textchanged event scope, I'm able to control the selected value by setting: ...SelectedValue = Combo.Text, but it doesn't work if I do it within the scope of textchanged event.... Why?

Comment: Isn't your Value of type of int? I'm guessing by
`comboToOther.SelectedValue = System.Int32.Parse(comboDetail[2]);` line. Then SelectedValue = Combo.Text won't work. Should convert text to int.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an error in your code?

Here is a working sample:

```
// Fields
private const string NameColumn = "Name";
private const string IdColumn = "ID";

private DataTable table;
```

Next, initialization

```
// Data source
table = new DataTable("SomeTable");
table.Columns.Add(NameColumn, typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add(IdColumn, typeof(int));

table.Rows.Add("First", 1);
table.Rows.Add("Second", 2);
table.Rows.Add("Third", 3);
table.Rows.Add("Last", 4);

// Combo box:
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = NameColumn;
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = IdColumn;
this.comboBox1.DataSource = table;
this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
this.comboBox1.TextChanged += comboBox1_TextChanged;
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Event handlers - TextChanged:

```
private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (table.Rows[i][NameColumn].ToString() == this.comboBox1.Text)
        {
            this.comboBox1.SelectedValue = table.Rows[i][IdColumn];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Event handlers - SelectedIndexChanged:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do here what is required
}
```

With this code, as soon as user types full name of item into combo box, SelectedIndexChanged is invoked through TextChanged.

There is also such thing as [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx), [AutoCompleteSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource.aspx). Don't know where they fit into your application.